# Bijective mapping of integers

Tags: c++, bijection

*English is not my native language: sorry for my mistakes. Thank you in advance for your answers.*

I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to check to what extent two sets with the same number of integers--in whatever order--are bijective.

Example :

```
int ArrayA [4] = { 0, 0, 3, 4 };
int ArrayB [4] = { 4, 0, 0, 3 };
```

ArrayA and ArrayB are bijective.

My implementation is naive.

```
int i, x=0;    
std::sort(std::begin(ArrayA), std::end(ArrayA));
std::sort(std::begin(ArrayB), std::end(ArrayB));
for (i=0; i<4; i++) if (ArrayA[i]!=ArrayB[i]) x++;
```

If x == 0, then the two sets are bijective. Easy.

My problem is the following: I would like to count the number of bijections between the sets, and not only the whole property of the relationship between ArrayA and ArrayB.

Example :

```
int ArrayA [4] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 }
int ArrayB [4] = { 3, 1, 3, 0 }
```

Are the sets bijective as a whole? No. But there are 2 bijections (0 and 0, 1 and 1).

With my code, the output would be 1 bijection. Indeed, if we sort the arrays, we get:

ArrayA = 0, 0, 0, 1;
ArrayB = 0, 1, 3, 3.

A side-by-side comparaison shows only a bijection between 0 and 0.

Then, my question is: 
*Do you know a method to map elements between two equally-sized sets and count the number of bijections, whatever the order of the integers?*

## Solved!

The answer given by Ivaylo Strandjev works:

1. Sort the sets,
2. Use the [std::set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) function,
3. Profit.

Comment: How about something along the lines of `int i=0,j=0,count=0; while (i<n && j<n) { if (A[i] == B[j]) ++i,++j,++count; else if (A[i] < B[j]) ++i; else ++j; }`? Assuming `A` and `B` are sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the number of elements that are contained in both sets. This is called set intersection and it can be done with a standard function - [set_intersection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/), part of the header algorithm. Keep in mind you still need to sort the two arrays first.

Comment: Fantastic! It seems to be the solution.

Comment: A lot more elegant than my suggestion. =]

Comment: After some tests: it IS the solution. Thanks Ivaylo!

Comment: @GuillaumeLethuillier If you are convinced that this is the solution you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @BartvanNierop: It may appear elegant, but this actually is a lot slower as it constructs the intersection whereas your solution (in comment) avoids that. The algorithm you provided is actually the canonical one, and probably used inside `set_intersection`.

Comment: @MSalters I had assumed that `set_intersection` would indeed be slower, and using my algorithm internally. =]

Comment: @MSalters To add to my previous comment, I'd go with Knuth and use `set_intersection` until it proved to be too slow in practice.

Comment: To join the discussion: @BartvanNierop your solution is faster and uses no extra memory, however it is harder to maintain or read as it is less obvious what it does.
I think what you say is quite right - use set_intersection unless it proves too slow.